# Better promotion of new sites

Tags: feature-request, notifications, information-display, sister-site

I think the English Stack Exchange site is "the greatest thing since sliced bread", however I only got to know it by luck (I think I was looking for a link to Superuser or Meta Stack Exchange). So I think it would be cool if you guys promote new sites a little better to the old user base.

**Proposal:**

- Treat them like badges (they would get the same kind of alert)
- Put new sites on top (next to the little envelope) for the first 2 weeks

Answer (score 6):

Here's how one might find out about the new SE 2.0 sites:

**Random sidebar advertisements**

[image: English Language & Usage sidebar ad]

**The StackExchange dropdown menu**

[image: English Language & Usage in the all sites tab in the StackExchange dropdown menu]

**The footer of all launched Stack Exchange sites**

[image: English Language & Usage in the footer of all Stack Exchange sites]

[**Area 51 Proposal**](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1269/english-language-usage)

[image: English Language & Usage Area 51 Proposal]

**Tweets by Jeff Atwood and many other tweeters**

[image: Tweet by VonC on his commitment to English Language & Usage]

**Appearance on http://stackexchange.com**

[image: English Language & Usage question on stackexchange.com]

---

Given all of the following ways in which a user can discover new Stack Exchange sites, do we really need to annoy users more with banners or buttons appearing in prominent positions on the page where it's more likely that the user have no interest at all in the new site?

Comment: I feel I have found that site, because I was to lazy to write superuser in google or toolbar. I feel most users do not care about stackexchange.com. I get annoyed by a lot of things, but I would enjoy information that there is a new stackexchange site(even only one badge message after it was released).

Comment: you forgot the dedicated twitter accounts! http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/twitter-question-feeds-for-stack-exchange/

Comment: @Jeff Atwood the twitter is only popular in the US.

Comment: @JeffAtwood I thought that's specifically for promoting popular questions from that site? Or a convenience for twitter users, or... something. Never really groked what that new feature was for, hmmmm

Comment: @01: Twitter only popular in the US?  Certainly *not*!  Maybe it's not popular where you are (whereever that is, your profile is mum on it), or just not popular in your circles.  It *is* quite popular here in Germany.

Answer (score 3):

Other Stack Exchange sites show up as sidebar ads all the time for me:

[image]

Comment: You might be right, but I did not see it. By default I ignore commercials, maybe I'm just younger and very used to pointless text all over this world.